# Split a string using regex or other optimized way

Tags: regex, scala

I have a very simple string of the form

```
YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
```

Basically a full date/time string. Say an example is

```
20170224134523
```

Above implies

```
year: 2017
month: 02
day:24
hour:13
min:45
sec:23
```

I want to split it so that i can have it in variables (year, month, day, hour, min, sec). This is in Scala I want to. I was thinking should I use a 6-Tuple and on the right side I will use a regex or what as the most efficient way. If I want to do it in a concise way is what I am trying to think. Little bad with regular expressions. 
Can anyone help?

I may want to have each variable in the 6-tuple as option type because otherwise that will also do my sanity check? Say if any variable comes out as `None`, I want to throw an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.text.SimpleDateFormat` handles this kind of date parsing well.

```
scala> val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddkkmmss")
sdf: java.text.SimpleDateFormat = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@8e10adc0

scala> val date = sdf.parse("20170224134523")
date: java.util.Date = Fri Feb 24 13:45:23 PST 2017
```

You can get the date, day, hours, etc from a successful parse of the date as the API shows below.

```
scala> res0.get
getClass   getDate   getDay   getHours   getMinutes   getMonth   getSeconds   getTime   getTimezoneOffset   getYear
```

Further, I'd suggest wrapping the `parse` call in a `Try` to handle the successful and unsuccessful parsing.

```
scala> val date = Try(sdf.parse("20170224134523"))
date: scala.util.Try[java.util.Date] = Success(Fri Feb 24 13:45:23 PST 2017)

scala> val date = Try(sdf.parse("asdf"))
date: scala.util.Try[java.util.Date] = Failure(java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "asdf")
```

Here's the same thing using the newer `LocalDateTime` instead of `Date` and it's deprecated methods.

```
LocalDateTime.parse("20170224134523", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yMMddkkmmss"))

java.time.LocalDateTime = 2017-02-24T13:45:23
```

Comment: Nice, except all those `get` methods have been deprecated. Is there an accepted alternative?

Comment: Java overhauled the date and time apis semi-recently. I think the new equivalent would be `LocalDateTime.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss"))`

Comment: Note that `yMMddkkmmss` seems to work with `DateTimeFormatter` as expected but does not return the desired date with `SimpleDateFormat`. `SimpleDateFormat` works with `yyyyMMddkkmmss`.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a date string it probably makes sense to use a dedicated date parsing library and parse to a datetime type.  Fortunatly, java provides a very good one with the `java.time` package.

```
val dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("20170224134523", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss"))
```

Which will produce a `LocalDateTime` object (date and time without a timezone attached).  If you need more complicated string parsing you can use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to customize the date format exactly as you need it.

Comment: Thank you. How do I wrap this in Try and return Option(of datatime) or None if the parsing fails?

Comment: @curiousengineer This method will throw exception on error, so you can just wrap in a try as normal `Try(...).toOption`

Answer (score 0):

With such a predictable format you can grab it by position using a substring function (from, to) into a date class.

The regex pattern to grab the sections as groups is:

`(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cjaSXg/1)

Comment: But there are chances the string might be garbled too.

Comment: If you can post all the possible variants in the OP, then we can come up with a pattern that handles them.